# convert a plot in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, png

[image: obtained by a 128 x 128 image]

I have a plot obtained by a 128 x 128 image, realized with the library matplotlib.pyplot. The plot was saved as png with total dimension (480,640,4). How i convert the data of image (128 x 18) in a numpy array (128 x 128)?

Comment: If it's saved as a png, all internal structure is lost. You need to cater an image processing algo to extract your image, then resize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library:

```
import imageio
image = imageio.imread('image.png')
```

You imported image is numpy array.

Comment: but in this way i should get a np array with dimension (480,640,4), of the total plot. How can i obtain the data only of the image ,which is a 128 x 128?

Comment: @kascodegama1 I am not sure if I understand your question. Maybe sharing your png file here would help us see the issue.